# How can select an element generated by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to activate a slideDown() onclick with an element that has been generated by js.

I downloaded a script from ryanfait.com which allows you to customise the look of radio buttons. This works fine but when I try and apply an action to the generated element (in this case a span) it doesn't work. How can I work around this?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="radiocont">
                                <label>Yes</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="styled" value="yes" name="watertank" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="radiocont">
                                <label>No</label>
                                <input type="radio" class="styled" value="no" name="watertank" />
                            </div>
```

When the DOM loads the inputs are replaced by spans that look like this:
`<span class="radio" title="yes" style="background-position: 0pt 0pt;"></span>`

When you click on one of the spans I want to activate slideDown(). Here is my js:`$('[title="yes"]').click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('.secondq:first').slideDown('slow');
});`

Can anyone assist?

Comment: You need to make sure that the click function is being binded after the spans have been swapped in. You could try jquery's .live()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to *"Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future."*

```
// .live()
$('[title="yes"]').live("click", function() { 
    $(this).nextAll('.secondq:first').slideDown('slow'); 
});

// .delegate() (not entirely sure of your structure, the below may need
// to be modified accordingly
$('.radiocont').delegate("span[title='yes']", "click", function() { 
    $(this).nextAll('.secondq:first').slideDown('slow'); 
});
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `delegate`, which would be better for this scenario if all the inputs are contained with the `radiocont` div.

Comment: This works: `$('.radiocont').live("click", function() { 
    $(this).nextAll('.secondq:first').slideDown('slow'); 
});`
but as you can see only by using the parent div to the generated span. When I apply it to `span[title="yes"]` it doesn't work?

Comment: Ok, one sec. This works fine if i do `$(.radiocont).nextAll()` but not if I use `$(this)`, thus activating everything else. What do I do?